# cloning a git project

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-clone

Hey guys I have been trying to connect my R to to the project on gitlab for a couple of days but I keep running into error. I researched it online and tried every step suggested but it still did not work for me. When I use the https link and open a new project in R, enter my credentials and clone the git repository, I get the following error

error: invalid path ' Monthly internal audit code '
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

I read online that I need to use 'git config --system core.longpaths true' to read files with long names but it did not work either. I have previously been able to clone the project with no errors so I don't think there is an issue with the file name. I have tried many other solutions as well but nothing is working. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me isolate the problem and fix it.

Comment: Can you show us the exact commands you're running? If it's a public repository, can you share the URL in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not share the repository. It is a private one. I figure it may probably be something to do with my working directory? The git folder is saved in C drive. Does that mean I also have to save the working tree in the exact folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: invalid path ' Monthly internal audit code '

The filename has a leading and a trailing spaces and it seems you're on a graphical environment that doesn't allow such filenames.

The only way to fix it is to clone the repository on a Unix/Linux OS (try WSL2, docker, a virtual machine), fix the filename and commit.